# Simulate a click on JavaScript function in Java

Tags: java, javascript

I'm writing a program that interacts with a website automatically in Java. I figured out how to build and send GET/POST requests to simulate a click or form submit. But I encountered a link that runs a JavaScript function.

```
<a href="javascript:function()">Run</a>
function function()
{
    document.myform.submit();
}
```

After clicking, the webpage is redirected to another URL.
How do I simulate this behavior in Java?

Comment: what is the function doing? we can't help unless we know what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always had the best luck with HTMLUnit.  It uses apache http and handles all the interaction pretty intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing library like Selenium or HttpClient to interact with a website.

Comment: ... or HtmlUnit. It has JavaScript and Dom support.